# During what part of activity life cycle various android annotations are called?

Tags: android, android-annotations

Currently I am moving my android project to android-annotations. I am having difficulty in understanding the sequence in which annotations are called. Due to wrong sequence I am getting nullPointerExceptions.

As an example usecase, I am trying to use @ViewById in Fragment. However I am getting nullPointerException in onCreateView() and onResume().

Documentation explaining about at what time in activity life cycle, which annotation will be triggered will be very helpful.

Following is small section of my code :-

```
@EFragment
public class DiscoverFragment extends Fragment {
    @ViewById(R.id.dishList)
    PullToRefreshListView mPullToRefreshView;

    @ViewById
    LinearLayout noDataAvailable;

    @ViewById
    LinearLayout dataAvailable;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discover, container, false);

        if (cursorStringDistance == null) {
            mPullToRefreshView.setMode(Mode.PULL_FROM_START);
            mPullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(oneRefresher);
        } else {
            mPullToRefreshView.setMode(Mode.BOTH);
            mPullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(bothRefresher);
        }

        ListView actualListView = mPullToRefreshView.getRefreshableView();
        actualListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (dishListDistance.size() == 0) {
            noDataAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dataAvailable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            noDataAvailable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dataAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

I am getting nullPointerException for line `mPullToRefreshView.setMode(Mode.PULL_FROM_START);` and `noDataAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`.

Comment: please show some code

Comment: @nikis added code in question

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an `@AfterViews` annotated method, the injected `View` fields will be available there. In case of `Fragment`s AA injects the `View` fields in the `onViewCreated()` method. If you want to understand the lifecycle, inspect the generated class.